# Get models in Django that have all of the values in ManyToMany field (AND-query, no reverse lookups allowed)

Tags: django, python-2.7

I have such a model in `Django`:

```
class VariantTag(models.Model):
    saved_variants = models.ManyToManyField('SavedVariant')
```

I need to get all `VariantTag` models that have saved_variants `ManyToMany` field with exact ids, say `(250, 251)`, no more, no less. By the nature of the code that I am dealing with there is no way I can do reverse lookup with `_set`. So, I am looking for a query (or several queries + additional python code filtering) that will get me there but in such a way:

```
query = Q(...)
tag_queryset = VariantTag.objects.filter(query)
```

How is it possible to achieve?

I should probably stress out: supplied saved variants (e.g. `(250, 251)` should be `AND` - ed, not `OR` - ed.

Comment: Why is reverse lookups relevant? Ah, you actually want to do this from the other side but think you can't?

Comment: Idk, I can be just wrong. I want to actually filter on `saved_variants__in=`, the way it is specified in the answer + by foreign keys and other parameters. If I add any additional parameters to `saved_variants__in` query, it always gives me nothing.

Comment: Let's say SavedVariant has a field "name". If you want all variant tags who have saved variants with a name field equal to "Bob", you do `VariantTag.objects.filter(saved_variants__name='Bob')`. But maybe it's not what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Use **`in`** lookup

```
tag_queryset = VariantTag.objects.filter(saved_variants__in=[250,251])
```

Comment: Is it possible to add additional property for filtering, e.g. `VariantTag.objects.filter(name=..., saved_variants__in=[250,251])`?

Comment: Yup, it is possible

Comment: Somehow, not working as long as I use a foreign key model parameter. E.g.: `VariantTag.objects.filter(variant_tag_type__name='Name_of_the_tag', saved_variants__in=saved_variant_ids)`. But I checked DB, it is there.

Comment: I guess its an issue of the additional join that I need to make to retrieve additional parameters. Maybe will ask a new question. Its like VariantTag -> VariantTagType. The latter contains all parameters.

Comment: I don't think that it is giving `AND` operation, but I think it is `OR`, right? I figured the issue with my foreign key and now I see that this solution does not seem to work: it returns also the models where `saved_variants` is just one value, e.g. `250`, but that does not work for me as stated in the question.

Comment: [`in`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in) lookup is kind of `OR`

Answer (score 0):

So far I was able to achieve `AND` result by the following code:

```
tag_ids = VariantTag.objects.filter(variant_tag_type__name=tag_data['tag'],
                                        saved_variants__in=saved_variant_ids).values_list('id', flat=True).distinct()
for tag_id in tag_ids:
    saved_variants = list(VariantTag.objects.get(id=tag_id).saved_variants.all().values_list('id', flat=True))
    if all(s in saved_variant_ids for s in saved_variants) and len(saved_variants) == len(saved_variant_ids):
        return VariantTag.objects.get(id=tag_id)
```

So, I am doing the following:

1. Getting the `OR` - result
2. Iterating over the resulting ids of the retrieved model and for each one of them getting all of the ids of the `ManyToMany` field
3. Checking if all of the obtained ids of the `ManyToMany` field are in the required ids list (`saved_variant_ids`)
4. If yes - get the model by the id: `VariantTag.objects.get(id=tag_id)`

In my case there will be only one such model that have the required ids in `ManyToMany` field. If it is not the case for you - just append the ids of the model (in my case `tag_id`) to a list - then make a query for all of them.

If anyone has more concise way of doing `AND` `ManyToMany` query + code, would be interesting to see.